# Passing password at runtime

Tags: vb.net

I inserted a bindingsource and then created dataset and tableadapter through it.
In my connectionstring, did not select to include sensitive data to it (password)

Now when the application runs, it says Invalid Password and crashes.
Off course it is what we expect.
Now my question is, I want my application to load password that I have passed in a variable e.g. `vrMyPWD as string="abc123"` before it loads

```
Me.TblInvoicesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DbInvoicesDataSet.tblInvoices)
```

at from_load.  So there is no error and application works normally.

Please guide.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy:

```
TableAdapter.connection.connectionstring + = ";Password=abc123"
```

Answer (score 1):

declare  `vrMyPWD`  as global string and set it Using `HANDLE_CREATED` event